# How to launch a second launcher with an intent similar to opening an external app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I made a custom launcher application that I'm trying to get a button to launch the original launcher. Right now it looks like this:

```
public void click(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher2");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Is it not possible to launch a launcher the same way I launch other external apps?